# Returns a collection of values for each row with two or more conditions into one row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have data excel in different sheet, sheet1 and sheet2 like this:

sheet1

```
no.    colA     colB     colC
1      a        1        yet
2      a        2        done
3      a        3        yet
4      b        1        done
5      b        2        done
6      b        3        done
7      b        4        yet
8      b        5        done
```

i want the output in sheet2 like this

sheet2

```
no.    key     monev     
1      a        2        
2      b        1,2,3,5
```

how i return this with excel formula?

Comment: note that Excel is not Google Sheets, please select only one of those tags. I proposed a solution that would work in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

In Sheets you can use:

```cpp
=LET(keys,UNIQUE(TOCOL(B2:B,1)),
     {SEQUENCE(COUNTA(keys)),
      keys,
      MAP(keys,LAMBDA(key,JOIN(", ",FILTER(C2:C,key=B2:B,"done"=D2:D))))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Transform Filtered Data: Unique With Delimited Rows

```
=LET(data,Sheet1!B2:D9,crit,"done",dlm,", ",
    d,FILTER(DROP(data,,-1),TAKE(data,,-1)=crit),
    kc,TAKE(d,,1),
    k,UNIQUE(kc),
    n,SEQUENCE(ROWS(k)),
    mc,DROP(d,,1),
    m,BYROW(k,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(dlm,,FILTER(mc,kc=r)))),
    r,HSTACK(n,k,m),
    r)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in `Excel` one could try:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:C9,
     _ColA, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _ColB, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _ColC, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_ColA),
     HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Uniq)),
            _Uniq,
            BYROW(_Uniq, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(_ColB, (_ColA=x)*(_ColC="done"),""))))))
```

---

Or, if one have access to `GROUPBY()` then,

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(A2:A9,B2:B9,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0,,C2:C9="done")
```

---